# Sending one email when all jobs completes successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mail

I need to create backup jobs over several instances, I wonder if there is any way to send a single notification via mail only when jobs from all instances completed successfully.

Comment: Hmmm... I can suggest slightingly different approach. Setup your jobs to mail you once one of them failed. If you have no err mail you are happy for a day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've achieved this is to add two steps to each backup job.  The first writes to a results table; it doesn't matter where this lives so long as all jobs can reach it.  The second step runs `sp_start_job`, targetting a common, new job.

This new job has three steps.  One, check the results table.  If any backup job has not yet reported then stop.  If all backup jobs have reported success then continue.  Step 2 - reset the results table.  Step 3 - send the email.  Two and three can be reversed depending on your tolerence for failure and your recovery practices.

The results table can be managed by `insert`/`truncate` or `update`/`update`.  You can get inventive with run numbers and history logging, too, I've that's needed.

You have to think how you want to recover from failed jobs?  Purge the results and start all again?  Re-start failed jobs only?  Have a precursor step which launches your backups, which then must be idempotent etc. etc.